# Pivot Table connected to another Worksheet Table that is linked to Access DB

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, vba

This is the table that is located in a password protected workbook, and it connected with a connection string to an Access DB Table.
The last 2 columns on the right, are calculated fields using Vlookup formula to another worksheet in this protected workbook.

I want to have a Pivot Table in another workbook (not protected), that will be able to connect to this Table, and have updated values every time the original table is modified (the Table in the attached screen-shot is growing every month once new records are added to the Access DB Table).

Is it possible ? 
I don't want to use the option of referencing to another sheet and select  a huge number of cells.
Is there a way to implement such a connection with Excel-VBA ? that might allow  me also to auto-enter the password in the background and not visible to the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect that workbook to the Access DB Table (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-an-Access-database-to-your-workbook-a3d6500c-4bec-40ce-8cdf-fb4edb723525?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Once that is done and the workbook has access to the data by inputting the credentials, you should be able to generate a pivot table in the now connected workbook that reads the Access DB table (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-external-data-db50d01d-2e1c-43bd-bfb5-b76a818a927b).

Comment: Not what I meant, I know how to connect an Excel Pivot to an Access DB. In fact, the attached screen-shot shows the result of such a connection, just here it's a table, as I need to add to more columns (as can be seen in my screen-shot) that are not part of the Access DB, these are calculated fields that use Vlookup to another worksheet in this workbook.  What I need is to have another workbook (besides the one described here) that has a PIVOT table that is connected to the entire table described here and the 2 calculated fields to the right.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to use the pivot table wizard on the workbook you wish to have the pivot table in, and simply select or create a dynamic range covering the data in the other workbook in which you have the calculated fields. To make sure the data always refreshes, a short VBA snippet can be written in the new workbook along the lines of: Sub AllWorksheetPivots()
Dim xTable As PivotTable
For Each xTable In Application.ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    xTable.RefreshTable
Next
End Sub